# mysql next record with order by

Tags: php, mysql

What I want is the following, I don't know if it's possible but I hope someone can help me.

I've 2 queries the first is a query to select a specified record.

The second query is to determine the next record. I know I can do this with:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > given_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

The problem now is that the ORDER BY is variable (a visitor can change the sort order)

I only got the id and the table to sort on (given by php). I want to know the next record also when the sort order is for example, ORDER BY date or ORDER BY time etc. etc.

Is there a way to do this with MYSQL?

Comment: what determines the next record? id+1?

Comment: yes, depending on the sort order

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible to do that. Did you try anything? What was the problem?

Comment: Well, I don't have any idea how to do this so i'm stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
-- skip 0, load one (same as LIMIT 1)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > given_id
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 0,1

-- skip one, load one
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > given_id
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 2 queries? Use one query 
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > given_id ORDER BY ?? (maybe with limit of pagesize)
and then get your records from the above result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table  where id = (select min(id) from table where id > given_id);
```